# Google Maps Info Window - Change my Location with JavaScript - Asp.NET

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, button, onclick, infowindow

Im trying after save a session redirect my webpage to another path of my asp.net project the code is down here:

```
(function (marker, data) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
        infoWindow.setContent('<div class="card" style ="width:200px;height:auto;">' +
        '<img class="card-img-top" src='+data.photo+' style="width:200px;height:auto;" >' +
        '<div class="card-body">'+
        '<h5 class="card-title">' + data.title + '</h5>' +
        '<p class="card-text">' + data.description + '</p>' +
        '<button id="btn_seedetails" >Click me</button>' +
        '</div>' + 
        '</div >' );
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('btn_seedetails'), 'click', sendit);                                           
   });

   function sendit() {
       '<%Session["ID_EVENT"] = "' + data.id + '"; %>';
       document.location.href = "AllConflicts.aspx";
       location.replace("AllConflicts.aspx")
   }
})(marker, data);
```

Comment: What does the browsers console say?

Comment: says : Uncaught

Comment: How many markers are you adding? Because they all have a button with the same ID. You can also use `data-id="342"` in the html and access that id in the sendit/clicked function

Comment: Im adding many markers as the data base has

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use the querystring to pass data:

```
function sendit() {
    window.location.href("AllConflicts.aspx?id=" + data.id);
}
```

also a nice ref for redirecting in JS [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Perhaps data.id is not available in the function. You might want to use an input parameter for the `sendit` function.

Comment: Still not working i think its because of the localhost link

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or something?

Comment: I already resolved , i used c# to response redirect and in which listener i equal my data.id to a hidden field

Comment: So the title of the question is not accurate anymore? ;-) "Change my Location with JavaScript"